# Avalanche: Finding assetID values for a given address

Tags: avalanche

## Context

The Avalanche documentation has a section on [eth_getAssetBalance](https://docs.avax.network/build/avalanchego-apis/contract-chain-c-chain-api#eth_getassetbalance).

Here's the example call shown:

```sh
curl -X POST --data '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_getAssetBalance",
    "params": [
        "0x8723e5773847A4Eb5FeEDabD9320802c5c812F46",
        "latest",
        "3RvKBAmQnfYionFXMfW5P8TDZgZiogKbHjM8cjpu16LKAgF5T"
    ],
    "id": 1
}' -H 'content-type:application/json;' 127.0.0.1:9650/ext/bc/C/rpc
```

In that call, the `assetID` value specified is:

```
3RvKBAmQnfYionFXMfW5P8TDZgZiogKbHjM8cjpu16LKAgF5T
```

## Question

For a given address, how do we get a list of associated `assetID` values?

Comment: any luck with that? don't find anything on the matter